# How to vertical and horizontal align the left column in Tablularx?

Tags: tabularx

I created a table using `tabularx` package and tried to vertically and horizontally align the contents on the left column. How can I do so?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
    {\small\textbf{Column 1}}
    & {\small \textbf{Column 2}}\\
    \midrule
    \makecell{5} & \begin{itemize}
    \itemindent=-13pt
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
    \end{itemize}\\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Current output looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}   % <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep,        % <-- new list setup
                  leftmargin=*,
                  label=$\bullet$,
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},
                  before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
                  }

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
    \small\textbf{Column 1}
    & \small \textbf{Column 2}  \\
    \midrule
5   &   \begin{tabitem}
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 2
            \item Item 3
        \end{tabitem}\\
    \midrule
  \end{tabularx}
  
\end{document}
```

or

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}   % <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep,        % <-- new list setup
                  leftmargin=*,
                  label=$\bullet$,
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},
                  }
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  
\begingroup
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
    \small\textbf{Column 1}
    & \small \textbf{Column 2}  \\
    \midrule
5   &   \begin{tabitem}
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 2
            \item Item 3
        \end{tabitem}\\
    \midrule
  \end{tabularx}
\endgroup
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Can't believe vertical alignment is so complicated.